# How to use multiple predicates in functional methods in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, functional-interface

I have the following expression written in a standard java-style with "if".

```
val punctuationChars = setOf('!', '?', '.')
if (text[index] in punctuationChars &&
         text[index + 1].isWhitespace() &&
         text[index + 2].isUpperCase()
        ){return index}
```

I want to rewrite it kotlin-style. I got something like this:

```
 text.indexOfFirst { it in punctuationChars && (((it + 1).isWhitespace()) && (it + 2).isUpperCase()) }
```

And it absolutely does not work. But. If i use just like that:

```
text.indexOfFirst { it in punctuationChars }
```

It's working. So, how can i use multiple predicates in functions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're doing this:

```
it in punctuationChars && (it + 1).isWhitespace()
```

What's `it` here? This function is being used with `text.indexOfFirst` which iterates over each `Char` in a `String`. So `it` is a `Char`, which you're using correctly with `it in punctuationChars` - "is this character in this set of characters?"

But in the next condition, you're treating `it` like an **index**. You're trying to see if the next character in the string is whitespace - but you don't have the current character's index, you have *the character itself*. `(it + 1).isWhitespace()` effectively checks the next character [*in the code table*](https://www.ascii-code.com/) (every character has a code number).

---

So to do it the way you're approaching it here, you need access to the *index*. You *could* do something like this:

```
text.withIndex().indexOf { indexed -> 
    // using nullable stuff here protects you from invalid index exceptions
    text.elementAtOrNull(indexed.index + 1)?.isWhitespace() == true
}
```

which wraps each element in an `Indexed` you can access (the element itself is the `value` property). Personally I'm not a fan, you're working on individual list elements but then using the index property to go poking around *the rest* of the list - I feel like if you're going to do that, just work with the indices directly, and access each element using that:

```
text.indices.firstOrNull { index ->
    // every element accessed through an index
    text[index] in punctuationChars &&
    text[index + 1].isWhitespace()
    ...
}
```

Again, accessing later indices like that is dangerous (what if it's the last character in the string?) so you should use `elementAtOrNull` - I'm just writing it like that for brevity.

---

If you *do* want to work with the chars themselves, in a safe way, you can use `windowed` which allows you to work on a sliding view of *n* elements from the list:

```
// partial windows allows for smaller windows with elements missing as you run into 
// the end of the list - you don't want that, you want it to end as soon as you can't
// fill a window (false is the default but I'm just putting it here for clarity!)
text.windowed(size=3, partialWindows=false).indexOfFirst { window ->
    window[0] in punctuationChars &&
    window[1].isWhitespace()
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is good to use *windowed* function. Something like:

```kotlin
text.windowed(3).indexOfFirst { it[0] in punctuationChars && it[1].isWhitespace() && it[2].isUpperCase() }
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct equivalent to your Java-like code is the following:

```
fun indexOfEndOfSentenceAndStartOfNextSentence(text: String): Int =
    (0 until text.length - 2).indexOfFirst {
        text[it] in ".!?" && text[it + 1].isWhitespace() && text[it + 2].isUpperCase()
    }
```

But using a regex may be better:

```
private val pattern = """[!?.]\s\p{Lu}""".toRegex()
fun indexOfEndOfSentenceAndStartOfNextSentence(text: String): Int =
    pattern.find(text)?.let { it.range.first } ?: -1
```

Comment: yep, regex will be better 100%. Try it, please.